# Use the Contour Integral to Show a Fourier Transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

Well, this is a physics class problem, and I did not learn anything about the contour integral. But I wish to show that:

> Use the contour integration to show that the transformation of $$f(x)={{1}\over{x^2+a^2}}$$ is $$f(k)={\pi\over a}e^{-|k|a}.$$

Could anyone give me any hint about this?

I can only get: $f(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-ikx}{{1}\over{x^2+a^2}}dx$, 
but I have no idea how to move on to integrate this. Any help, please.

Answer (score 4):

This is done using [residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) and [Jordan's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma). For example, if $k<0$, you can close the contour of integration by a semicircle of infinite radius in the upper half plane, and then the integral becomes
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ikx}dx}{x^2+a^2}=2\pi i \sum_k\mathrm{res}_{z=z_k}\,\frac{e^{-ikz}}{z^2+a^2},$$
where the sum is taken over the singularities of $f(z)=\frac{e^{-ikz}}{z^2+a^2}$ in the upper half plane. In your case there is only one such point - a simple pole $z=ia$ (we assume $a>0$), and the residue is simply
$$\mathrm{res}_{z=ia}f(z)=\lim_{z\rightarrow ia}(z-ia)f(z)=\frac{e^{ka}}{2ia},$$
so that
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ikx}dx}{x^2+a^2}=2\pi i \frac{e^{ka}}{2ia}=\frac{\pi e^{ka}}{a}.$$
When $k>0$, Jordan lemma allows you to similarly close the contour in the lower half plane and the rest of the calculation is analogous (except that now you will have **minus** sum of the residues due to the change of contour orientation).